# Using custom loader and criteria in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Assume that in my existing production database, I have a table Students. Majority of students are ex. students, which I would like to separate from current students. More specifically, I'd like to keep Students table for students that are currently enrolled and move the other ones to Students_history table. Likewise with some other tables connected to Students. The motivation for this is that want to have (school_name, student_id) as a primary key, and sometimes same schools will reassign student_id, thus I will have same student_id for some student that graduated 10 years ago and another that is currently enrolled. This student_id is something beyond my control, it's from the data coming into the application. The second thing is that many operations on my table will be much faster, as there are much less current students than all students (including ones that graduated).

The best solution I was able to find includes defining triggers on Students table, where deleting them moves students (and other data that references student entries) to the corresponding Student_history table. The part I'm trying to figure out is how to make Hibernate work with this. I'd like to show entries from both tables (Students and Students_history) in the web app, just like it's working currently. To show this data in web interface, I'm using GWT, where data is fetched using:

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Students.class);
```

Using criteria helps greatly when sorting and filtering items in web app. I've tried specifying custom query for loading, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Students")
@Loader(namedQuery = "students")
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "students", query = "select * from students union all select * from students_history WHERE Id = ?", resultClass = Students.class)
```

After the query follows a definition of Students class. This does not work - the query that Hibernate generates with the forementioned criteria does not include any mention of students_history.

I'm using postgreSQL, Hibernate 4 and Java 1.6.

### My questions are:

1. Am I on the right track separating current and old students? By this, I mean using helper table and stored procedures upon deletion.
2. Can Hibernate criteria work with custom loading query defined with @Loader annotation? I expected that Hibernate will use my loader query as a basis for criteria. If this is possible, any code snippet or link will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Named queries are a feature that helps you reuse you HQL/SQL interrogations.

They don't anything to do with the Criteria API, which is a different way of selecting from the database. So there is no way the Criteria will use your loader query.

Think about is this way: the Criteria API builds an SQL query from scratch using the criteria you provide. In your case, it would have to first interpret your loader query and then build around it a correct SQL.